# Problems using delegates

Tags: c#

In the following code, I get the following warning:

The variable 'Result' is assigned but its value is never used

```
   bool Result;

        base.ExecuteTest(delegate(Selenium.ISelenium sel1)
        {
            return Result = false;

        });
```

Furthermore, in the following code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= ClientSiteCnt; )
        {
            return (Result = testcaseDel.Invoke());
        }
```

The delegate signature is

```
 public delegate bool TestCaseDelegate(Selenium.ISelenium sel);
```

How do I add the parameter (the delegate's parameter) in the .Invoke() method?

Comment: Honestly, your code does not make any sense to me. Why are you assigning Result a value, then return it? If anything I would expect horrendous side effects, using and assigning a variable outside of the delegate.
What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the side effects? This seems like something I genuinely don't know.

Comment: Why would you have a for loop which always ends in the first iteration?

Comment: if you are using delegates, you need to understand *how* parameters are passend into and out of the delegate source, *when* the delegate will be executed and in what state the passed parameters are. And the Result you use is a parameter passed using a trick, the delegate is executed in a different execution frame and has no direct access to local variables of the calling execution frame.  
You really should explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've made some tweaks and fixed issues. Learnt something today!

Answer (score 1):

about add parameter to Invoke method
you will just write it as

```
TestCaseDelegate testCaseDelegate =new TestCaseDelegate([method Name]);
testCaseDelegate .Invoke([parameter of type Selenium.ISelenium]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this message because you only assign a value to Result, but never use it.

What the compiler tries to tell you is: Why do you declare Result, assign values to it, but never use it?

Since you never use Result, your code samples will function exactly the same when you use:

```
    base.ExecuteTest(delegate(Selenium.ISelenium sel1) 
    { 
        return false; 
    });
```

and

```
    // for (int i = 0; i <= ClientSiteCnt; )  
    // {  
        return testcaseDel.Invoke(); 
    // }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Yeah that is a much better example and I am going the way you've written too. Any idea on the second part of my post?

Comment: I think Space Cracker answered this for me.